# How to translate android system

Tags: android

I want to add my native language to android all system like other Lang's , I mean how to translate it to my language??
Please help an  give me some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

- First, check if you language is supported and note the Language Code. follow the below link
  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/4419860?hl=en
  -Then, Read the how to guide
  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization